# SQL Server and EF Core on Ubuntu, error occurred during the pre-login handshake

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, ubuntu, entity-framework-core

I want to develop .Net Core on Ubuntu 22.04. I can add migrations but can not update DB
This is My connection string:

```
"Server=reza;Database=CodeFirst_Db;User Id=sa;Password={MyPassword};MultipleActiveResultSets=true
```

and it is the error:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)

I have searched in Google but I didn't find anything.
Can someone share a document about it please?
Should I install Docker?

I have installed .NET Core SDK and runtime and EF Core and SQL server (From This [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver16))
I have installed: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design

Comment: You're trying to use Active Directory authentication by specifying `Trusted_Connection=True;` . You can only do that when client and server are both joined to the same Active Directory domain. Check [Use Active Directory authentication with SQL Server on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: I suspect you only wanted to use SQL Server Authentication. If that's the case, remove `Trusted_Connection=True;`. It would be a *very* good idea to *not* use the `sa` account too

Comment: Guys i removed Trusted Connection but i have this error again

Comment: Nothing to do with `Trusted_Connection` that is a separate issue which you will hit once the login handshake happens. This is a TLS issue (before login), so there is probably a TLS version or cipher mismatch between client and server. Can you get a Wireshark trace on the Client and Server Hello, and compare the TLS version and the list of ciphers?

Comment: If you have access to the `reza` SQL Server using SSMS, DBeaver, etc., what's the output of `SELECT @@VERSION` when run on it? Seems like it could be an old version of SQL Server that hasn't been [updated to support modern TLS 1.2 protocols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/tls-1-2-support-microsoft-sql-server).